# What does Google index after a mod-rewrite?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I know if you do a 301 redirect Google indexes the final page you end up at.But what happens if you redirect with a mod_rewrite?  Does Google know where it ends up and index the final page?

Comment: mod_rewrite is purely internal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google knows nothing about it because mod_rewrite doesn't change anything the user can see. mod_rewrite sits at the front of your webserver, modifying the URLs that it serves. The URLs provided by the client do not change though.

Comment: "Google knows nothing about it because mod_rewrite doesn't change anything the user can see."  Mod_rewrite changes the page the bot receives. Google could look at it and say, "Wait a minute!  That's not what I requested." and decide to index the page data under the page title it received rather than what it requested.

Comment: How does it know that it's not the page it requested? The bot never sees the modified url.